# Make a timer using setInterval()

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I'm trying to make a timer in javascirpt and jQuery using the `setInterval` function.
The timer should count down from 90 to zero (seconds).

The code that I'm using for this:

```
setInterval(settime(), 1000);
```

in this `settime()` sets the var `time` (started on 90) -1, this action has to happen once every second.
My problem is that I don't get how to let this action happen 90 times; I tried using a for loop but then the counter counts from 90 to 0 in 1 second.

Does anyone knows a better alternative?

Comment: You must pass a function, not call it! Just `setInterval(settime, 1000)`, no `settime()`!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function timer(seconds, cb) {
  var remaningTime = seconds;
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    cb();
    console.log(remaningTime);
    if (remaningTime > 0) {
      timer(remaningTime - 1, cb); 
    }
  }, 1000);
}

var callback = function() {
  console.log('callback');
};

timer(90, callback);
```

Caution in using setInterval, may not work as you expect http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#other.timeouts

Answer (score 5):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
var count = 90;
var interval = setInterval(function(){
  setTime();
  if (count === 0){
    clearInterval(interval); // Stopping the counter when reaching 0.
  }
}, 1000);
```

I don't have the code you need but I'm sure you'll need to update the count at some point on your page.

You can cancel an interval with `clearInterval` which needs the ID of the interval that's created when you call `setInterval`

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` keeps calling  your function at each second (since you use 1000).

So `setInterval` expects a function as its first argument, which is the function which will be called periodically. But instead of passing `settime`, you pass its returned value. That won't work, unless `settime` returns a function.

Instead, try

```js
setInterval(settime, 1e3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `.data()` , `.queue()` , `animate()` , `.promise()` ; to stop "countdown" can call `$(element).clearQueue("countdown")`

```js
var counter = function counter(el) {
   return $(el || window).data({
    "start": {
      "count": 0
    },
    "stop": {
      "count": 1
    },
    "countdown": $.map(Array(90), function(val, key) {
                   return key
                 }).reverse(),
    "res": null
  })
  .queue("countdown", $.map($(this).data("countdown")
    , function(now, index) {
      return function(next) {
        var el = $(this);
        $($(this).data("start"))
        .animate($(this).data("stop"), 1000, function() {
          el.data("res", now)
          $("pre").text(el.data("res"));
          next()
        });
      }
    })
  )
  .promise("countdown")
  .then(function() {
    $("pre").text($(this).data("res"))
    .prevAll("span").text("countdown complete, count:");
  });
  };
  $("button").on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).is("#start")) {  
       counter();
       $("pre").text(90).prev("span").html("");
       $(window).dequeue("countdown");
    }
    else {
       $(window).clearQueue("countdown").promise("countdown")       
      .then(function() {
         $("pre").prevAll("span").html(function(_, html) {
         return html.replace("complete", "stopped")
       });
       })       
    }
  });
```

```css
pre {
  font-size:36px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<button id="start">start</button><button id="stop">stop</button>
<br />
<span></span>
<br />
<pre>90</pre>
```